# Fetch teacher and subject wise details in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

#### Table `tution`

```
institute | name | subject | students

--------------------------------------------
institute1 | john | maths | mary

institute1 | john | maths | stacy

institute2 | john | maths | david

institute2 | john | science | bruce

institute1 | tim | maths | steve

institute2 | tim | science | harry

institute1 | john | science | peter
```

Each teacher in each subject should have limited students, suppose 25 students should be present for each subject in class.

So, here I request a SQL query to fetch the details of each teacher in a searched institute and their subject strength where institute is equal to searched institue.

Show only that teacher details which is not having strength of 25 students in each subject where institue is equal to searched institute.

I'm able to fetch the data but it takes two queries and some php functions to get the result.

These are my queries

```
select * from tution where institute = '$search_institute'
```

From this query I fetch the values of institue. Then I build a two php functions to count the name values and in that another function is there to check the name values subject and then recheck the count with each subject.

This is the count php function in which another with the help of another function I will get the subject value

```
select count(*) from tution 
where name = '$institue_name' 
  and subject = '$institute_subject'.
```

First getting the rows of searched institute and then, with the values of institute and with a `foreach` loop and another count SQL query builtin PHP function I am creating an array with count values.

The problem is, I am getting the result in an array two different arrays as institute-teacher list and teacher count, and then I had to do a lot of work like merging and sorting.

I need a simple complete SQL solution for this.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: thanks, for your comments but this is not my homework.

Comment: Either way - although I appreciate coming up with code is sometimes difficult, Stack Overflow is not meant to be a "please write my code for me" site. This would be a much more useful question if you had a specific, concrete problem while trying to build this yourself

Comment: first getting the rows of searched institute and then after with the values of institute and with foreach loop and another count sql query built in php function i am creating an array with count values, but the problem is i am getting the result in an array two different arrays as institute teacher list and teacher count and then after i had to do a lot of work like merge and sort. So, that's why i am here to take some guidance from experts to resolve my problem. My English is little weak. Thanks Pekka

Comment: Show us your code first, please. You said you already had something? We need something we can work with.

Comment: "select * from tution where institute = '$search_institute'" from this query i fetch the values of institue. then i build a two php functions to count the name values and in that another function is there to check the name values subject and then recheck the count with each subject. This is the count php function in which another with the help of another function i will get the subject value
"select count(*) from tution where name = '$institue_name' and subject = '$institute_subject'". Please guide me. Thanks slhck.

Comment: Your second query references a column "name" which is not present in the table structure you've shown at first?

Comment: sathya. Thanks for your reply i had edited the question with column name as it `name` while writing teacher names i had given column as teacher sorry. my mistake. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you combine both into a single SQL?

> SQL query to fetch the details of each teacher in a searched institute
>   and their subject strength where institute is equal to searched
>   institue.
>
> Show only that teacher details which is not having strength of 25
>   students in each subject where institue is equal to searched
>   institute.

---

```
select name, subject, count(students) as Student_count
from tution 
where institute = '$search_institute'
group by name, subject
having count(students) != 25
```

the group by allows for aggregation of data across columns. Here, you're grouping the result set by Name  & their subject along with the count. The where clause filters out the result to provide only those institutes matching `'$search_institute'` and the having clause filters our groups not having student count of 25

Comment: Thanks Sathya for helping me resolve this problem. Any how I got answer in phpfreaks. Thanks once again for your help. I got the answer as "SELECT institute, teacher, subject, count(students) AS StudentCount
FROM tuition
WHERE institute = 'someinstitute'
GROUP BY institute, teacher, subject
HAVING StudentCount < 25" . Thanks Thanks Thanks Sathya.

Comment: You're welcome, @bhrmalik. If this helped, you should mark this as accepted answer by clicking on the green checkbox

Comment: Thanks. Sathya I had clicked.